# OpenCart Paypal Issue with LKR

Tags: php, paypal, opencart, currency

I'm using opencart 1.5.6.4 and using LKR (Sri Lanka Rupee) as default currency. I have followed [this](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=136&t=65005) thread and enable paypal checkout with LKR currency.

But when I click **Confirm Order** and redirect to paypal page to pay, paypal page display USD amount without convert LKR amount to USD. For example, when I have to checkout LKR 105.00 item, paypal page display it as $ 105.00. But it should display as approximately $ 0.80 (with current LKR to USD conversion).

**Opencart shopping cart total.**

[image: opencart_img]

**Paypal order summary display as below.**

[image: paypal_ing]

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that your shopping cart is passing the currency code as "USD" to PayPal that's why you see the  USD on the checkout page .

And the other thing is PayPal doesn't support "LKR" currency , so even if you send the currency code as "LKR" it will say something like "Currency not supported " .

You need to do the conversion in the Open Cart itself from LKR to USD and then send the amount to the PayPal .